# "overflow: hidden" is not working in Desktop outlook and Text overflow in I phones & Mis-alignment

Tags: css, overflow

I have used "`display: inline-block; height: 120px; overflow: hidden`" css property for product name in recommendations carousel, here the product name is not hiding as given in the above CSS property for Outlook desktop application and in I phones as well. Which css property would work effectively for iphones and outlook desktop applications.

I have tried by changing various CSS properties but not working for I phones and desktop outlook application.

Comment: what is your current output?